# Show different sidebar on taxonomy pages when a default is set

Tags: custom-taxonomy, sidebar

My theme holds below code in `sidebar.php`. I want to now make sure I can show a different sidebar when someone is viewing a custom taxonomy.

```
//Default sidebar
$selected_sidebar_replacement = 'Sidebar Widgets';

//If is page or single
if(is_singular()){
global $wp_query;
$post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$selected_sidebar_replacement = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', true);

//If default selected
if($selected_sidebar_replacement == '0' || $selected_sidebar_replacement == ''){
$selected_sidebar_replacement = 'Sidebar Widgets';
                    }

// Reset the global $the_post
wp_reset_query();

                }
```

I've already tried the below (above `//If default selected`), where "product-brand" is the slug of the custom taxonomy and where "Gear" is an existing (and working on other pages) sidebar, but it didn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
if(is_tax( 'product-brand' )){ $selected_sidebar_replacement = 'Gear'; }
```

Full `sidebar.php` code on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/CLD9DrUz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get something working where I just called the taxonomy (unspecific) and compared it to the current taxonomy I was viewing. This meant making too many iterations though, so I removed it and basically added a single conditional to check against the custom_post_type.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply create a new sidebar... It will be clearer for you and will lighten your sidebar.php.

Create a file in your theme folder : sidebar-thenameyouwant.php
put your sidebar code there like this ex :

```
    <div id="secondary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-xyz' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
```

in your themes function.php... add :

```
    register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Custom posts sb',
    'id' => 'sidebar-xyz',
    'description' => 'blablabla',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</aside>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

then in your custom taxonomy page you call the right sidebar

```
<?php get_sidebar('thenameyouwant');    ?>
```

it will automatically load the code from your sidebar-thenameyouwant.php

Of course, the new sidebar will be in your admin Appearance > Widgets... You can slide widgets into it or just edit the new sidebar file directly. If you want to load widgets you have to have the dynamic_sidebar php call like above...

hope this helps.

Comment: Issue is that the theme I'm using is calling the sidebar in the afterloop part, so if I call another sidebar in the "main" part of the code, it'll add a second sidebar. Unfortunatly unless I strip out all code that's currently there, this won't work. Should've maybe specified that, your answer is much appreciated though.

Comment: Tried the below, but it didn't work either.
`//Default
$selected_sidebar_replacement = 'Sidebar Widgets';
if( is_tax( 'product-brand' )){
   $selected_sidebar_replacement = 'Gear'; 
     //If is page or single
} elseif(is_singular()){
 global $wp_query;
 $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
 $selected_sidebar_replacement = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', true);

 //If default
 if($selected_sidebar_replacement == '0' || $selected_sidebar_replacement == ''){
  $selected_sidebar_replacement = 'Sidebar Widgets';}

 // Reset global $the_post
 wp_reset_query();
}`

Answer (score 0):

why not just do that ...

```
if (get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'xyz' && is_single() ) {
// your code for this sb 
}
else {
// for the other pages/posts
}
```

Comment: ah sorry you said custom taxonomy not post type. You could maybe use this if it is adapted to your config
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive

Comment: Also this should help 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Querying_by_taxonomy